# Using scrapy shell with splash return empty value

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm scraping this site: http://www.germandeli.com/Meats/Sausages which contains some dynamic content.

I am using scrapy shell with splash to render the javascript but it returns the empty value []. My system is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Here the code I used:

```
$ scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://www.germandeli.com/Meats/Sausages'
>>> response.xpath('*//h2[@class="item-cell-name"]/a/@href').extract()
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I forgot to add '&timeout=10&wait=5' in the end of the link!

```
scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=http://www.germandeli.com/Meats/Sausages&timeout=10&wait=5'
```

Comment: Scraping sausages? 

Comment: @GianfrancoP. Actually I scrape every product from the page, just take sausages  as an example :D